# VBA Worksheet Data extraction to search for multiple values

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I am tasked with pulling two specific rows of data from monthly sheets in a workbook.

Current code, using MyVal and a search box, is only compatible with one search. How can I change the code & searchbox function to be compatible with multiple searches?

Current code looks like this:

```
    Sub Set_Hyper()
     '   Object variables
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rCell As Excel.Range
    Dim fFirst As String
     '   {i} will act as our counter
    Dim i As Long
     '   Use an input box to type in the search criteria
    Dim MyVal As String
    MyVal = InputBox("What are you searching for", "Search-Box", "")
     '   if we don't have anything entered, then exit the procedure
    If MyVal = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

     '       Add a heading to the sheet with the specified search value
    With Cells(1, 1)
        .Value = "Found " & MyVal & " in the Link below:"
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    i = 2
     '       Begin looping:
     '       We are checking all the Worksheets in the Workbook
    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
         If wks.Name <> "Data" Then

         '       We are checking all cells, we don't need the SpecialCells method
         '       the Find method is fast enough
            With wks.Range("A:A")
             '           Using the find method is faster:
             '           Here we are checking column "A" that only have {myVal} explicitly

                Set rCell = .Find(MyVal, , , xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext, False)
             '           If something is found, then we keep going
                If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
                 '               Store the first address
                    fFirst = rCell.Address
                    Do
                     '                   Link to each cell with an occurence of {MyVal}
                        rCell.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 1), "", "'" & wks.Name & "'!" & rCell.Address
                        wks.Range("B" & rCell.Row & ":R" & rCell.Row).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 2)

                        Set rCell = .FindNext(rCell)
                        i = i + 1 'Increment our counter
                    Loop While Not rCell Is Nothing And rCell.Address <> fFirst
                End If
            End With
         End If
    Next wks
     '   Explicitly clear memory
    Set rCell = Nothing
     '   If no matches were found, let the user know
    If i = 2 Then
        MsgBox "The value {" & MyVal & "} was not found on any sheet", 64, "No Matches"
        Cells(1, 1).Value = ""
    End If
     '   Reset application settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking what you could do is create a UserForm with the following controls:

A text box
A Listbox
A button to add text to the listbox
Another button to run the VBA

The Textbox can hold the search string(s). You can make an event when you click the button to do the following:

1) Add the text from textbox to the listbox. Lookup the AddItem method to do this.
2) Clear the text box contents, so a new value can be added.

Once that's added you can add another for loop around your code to go through each item added to the listbox. That way you can do multiple searches based on what was added.

Hopefully this helps :)